# ¿Cómo acceder al HttpContext en Asp.Net Core 5.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

Estoy tratando de establecer  una variable de sesión accediendo al HttpContext

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("Empresa", "RACE");
```

pero me devuelve el siguiente error :
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase.HttpContext.get devolvió null.

***¿Cómo puedo resolver esto?***

controller:

```
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContext;

    public PeticionesController(IReadFile _readFile, IMailingRepository _mailingRepository, IPeticiones _peticiones,IPaginacion _paginacion, IFunctionApplication _funcion, IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext)
    {
        readFile = _readFile;
        mailingRepository = _mailingRepository;
        peticiones = _peticiones;
        paginacion = _paginacion;
        funcion = _funcion;
        httpContext = _httpContext;
        MockUpUser();

    }

    private void MockUpUser()
    { //AQUI EL ERROR
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Id", "9f1885b0bf-07a9-40dc-b226-285c862b04c22");
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("IdEmpresa", "Z123456");
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Empresa", "RACEXX");
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("RoleId", "administrador");
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("RoleName", "administrador");
    }
```

StartUp.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddSingleton<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor,   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();

            Peticiones.peticionesSize = Configuration.GetValue<int>("PageSize:PeticionesSize");

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Muestra el código de tu controlador

Comment: Arriel ...  Edite el post y agregue el codigo de la clase donde ocurre el error

Comment: que datos quieres obtener, cookies o los datos del token, o a que te refieres que te da error al acceder al httpcontext

Comment: Daniel ... Fijate en el post que cuando entro al constructor del controlador  invoco un metodo que se llama MockUpUser() ..alli es el error

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC pues eso, es lo que no entiendo, porque quieres inyectar `MockUpUser`en tu propio constructor, si quieres `MockUpUser` quieres que sea algo general, usa inyeccion de dependencias

Comment: Lo que quiero es tener esas variables inicializadas mientras realizo pruebas

Comment: @Efrain Mejias C, entonces solo declaralas al inicio de tu controlador, `public class Controller { httpcontext...} ` y si quieres algo más general y quieres tener acceso a esas variables de sesion y usarlas en tus otros métodos y controladores, usa inyección de depencias

Answer (score 2):

Solucione agregando `httpContext` antes de  `HttpContext.Session`  y el codigo quedo de esta manera:

Controlador:

```
    public class PeticionesController : Controller 
    { 
        private readonly IReadFile readFile;
        private readonly IPeticiones peticiones;
        private readonly IPaginacion paginacion;
        private readonly IMailingRepository mailingRepository;
        private readonly IFunctionApplication funcion;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContext;

        public PeticionesController(IReadFile _readFile, IMailingRepository _mailingRepository, IPeticiones _peticiones,IPaginacion _paginacion, IFunctionApplication _funcion, IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext)
        {
            readFile = _readFile;
            mailingRepository = _mailingRepository;
            peticiones = _peticiones;
            paginacion = _paginacion;
            funcion = _funcion;
            httpContext = _httpContext;
            MockUpUser();
        }

        private void MockUpUser()
        {
            httpContext.HttpContext.Session.SetString("Id", "e3574b97-6bcf-4ae3-943e-8d94d7d093c0");
            httpContext.HttpContext.Session.SetString("IdEmpresa", "Z123456");
            httpContext.HttpContext.Session.SetString("Empresa", "RACE");
            httpContext.HttpContext.Session.SetString("RoleId", "administrador");
            httpContext.HttpContext.Session.SetString("RoleName", "administrador");
        }
}
```

StartUp.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor,HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
           
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
 
        }
}
```